# Customizing Routes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i need to change my URL in my project

i have article "http://localhost:43524/home/Books/2"

the name for this article= "buy books free"

i went change this URL To

"http://localhost:43524/home/Books/buy-books-free"

and like [Customizing Routes in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035747/customizing-routes-in-asp-net-mvc)

how use the article title in my URL >
how make it ?

Comment: I guess this should answer your question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856068/custom-url-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: This is called a slug route. Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349412/how-to-implement-url-rewriting-similar-to-so/30363600#30363600) for one method of implementing it (but that still relies on passing the `ID` as well so that entering `.../home/Books/2` will result in `.../home/Books/2/buy-books-free` (i.e. the same as your seeing in the address bar now)